react-native-calendars AgendaList - make it scroll to today on opening the calendar - Flatlist props not working?
I am using the AgendaList of react-native-calendars in my App, and would like to include events in the past, so the user can scroll back to look at them. However I would like the AgendaList to scroll to today by default.
In the documentation I cannot find a prop for this.
I have tried to achieve the desired behaviour with flatlist props. However, even though the documentation states that the AgendaList extends FlatList props, whenever I try to use any of the FlatList props (I tried  by using getItemLayout with initialScrollIndex) the component does not react to them. I wonder why, and if it really extends FlatList or SectionList props, as I also have encountered the same issue when trying to use other props?
Does anybody have an Idea how to achieve this behaviour?
This currently is also an open question on StackOverflow: (I do not have enough reputation for comments..)
Make AgendaList scroll to today by default
And an open Github Issue.
